I need support to fix below issue in Selenium JAVA java: cannot access org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
java: cannot access org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
  bad class file: /C:/Users/USER/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-api/4.19.0/selenium-api-4.19.0.jar!/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.class
    class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

I am trying to Open chrome
POM.xml file
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.19.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.10.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>4.21.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.0</version>
</dependency>


Need to check the java version in your machine and provide the relevant dependency in the pom.xml file.
In my case, I have installed java 1.8 in my system .. Hence i make the below changes in the dependency .
<!-- Selenium API for Java 8 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version> <!-- Selenium 3.x is compatible with Java 8 -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- WebDriverManager to manage browser drivers -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- TestNG -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version> <!-- Example version compatible with Java 8 -->
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

